# php login - something wrong with the validation in fields

Tags: php

I have a problem with my login form, because if I put some text in password field and empty in the user/email field it the form will execute and redirect to index page.

**this the site**
http://www.itbotics.com/login.php

other validations is ok, I just want to make it safe.
thanks

**this is my code**

```
                    if ($user == $email && $pass = $password) {
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['mysesi'] = $name;
                        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                        echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";
                    } elseif (empty($email) || empty($password)) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                            <strong>Warning!</strong> Please fill out all fields.
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                            <strong>Warning!</strong> Incorrect combination of Email Address and Password.
                        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that you don't have required attributes in your form, so $user==$email can be equal && $pass=$password will always be equal because its an assignment

Comment: I sorry I will update the code because the $user and $pass is the data from the database

Comment: Another assumption. If you are using database , then there is no need to check if provided email and password are empty coz anyway database query will fail. And you might consider it doing before searching database or at client side

Comment: Now I realize, thanks a lot sir

Comment: its perfectly working now...thanks

Comment: Good website design. Fully responsive in my mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, maybe solution of your problem is here

```
if ($user == $email && $pass = $password) {
```

It should be:

```
if ($user == $email && $pass =**=** $password) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use &&(and) instead of ||(or)

Here

use this
   elseif (empty($email) && empty($password))

instead of
   elseif (empty($email) || empty($password))

Because in your condition if user enter any of the one either username or password then your condition become true.

So you have to use &&(AND) operator instead of ||(OR)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 if ($user == $email && $pass = $password)
```

to

```
if ($user == $email && $pass == $password)
```

You already got your answer but here are few suggestions that may be good for you.

Do basic form validation all client side like

```
<input type="email" required >
```

Will do email validation for you

```
<input type="password" required minlength="6" >
```

Will take password of min length 6 character. You don't have to check it.
Also "required" field makes sure that user can left those fields blank. HTML5 browser are required for those but I think most of the world have it.

In your php, do input validation before you execute database queries.

Comment: but using required can be edit by user through inspect element. also the password is auto generated by the system

Comment: I didn't mean that you should have only that. Its a layer of validation. Most of the basic users don't do this kind of inspect elements things. For those who do, you are also checking validation in php. So not a problem. Just try to use browsers feature to make your life easy